# Modifying saved plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having a problem right now. I have run an extremely heavy simulation and, thus, generated a plot with `matplotlib` containing the results and saved it (as .jpg). However, there are some elemnts of the plot I would like to change, such as labels size and one vertical line. Is there a straighforward way to do this using `matplotlib`? I know I could have stored the data and now just replot changing the parameters (and, actually, I have done this), but I was wondering whether there is an easier way. Maybe something like:

```
fig, ax = plt.figure(path_to_figure)
ax.set_ylabel("Y_label")
...
```

Comment: can you not change it while plotting ? Change everything before you save the `figure` .

Comment: Jpg is a lossy compression, so during the conversion, you lost already image information. Jpg is a general image file format - it does not store matplotlib objects (that's why you have a specific file format in GIMP to store the image in a format that allows you to modify elements later on). So, I guess the answer is no, no you probably cannot. Unless it is a separate title that you can change with GIMP or a similar image manipulation software.

Comment: I naturally can change before saving, but that was not my question. I asked whether there was a way to modify and already saved image. As a matter of fact, I changed the parameters and have ran the simulation again, but I would like to avoid this work in the future, because this simulation takes a lof of time to compute. Anyway, I thank you and that does make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below example, which gives you more idea on how you can do this while plotting everything.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

def f(t):
    return t ** 2

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.1)

noise = np.random.randn(len(t1)) * 0.04
# x coordinates for the lines
xcoords = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
# colors for the lines
colors = ['r','k','b']


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(t1, f(t1 + noise), color = 'hotpink', label='Values obtained by experiment', edgecolors='k')
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), ls='solid', label='Theoretical expectation', color='b')
plt.title(r'This is latex title example $\mathbf{E = m \times c^2}$', fontsize='small')
for xc,c in zip(xcoords,colors):
    plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

If you want to make all the fonts `bold`, you can also use below code to make everything `bold`:

```py
font = {'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   :  14 }
plt.rc('font', **font)

def f(t):
    return t ** 2

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.1)

noise = np.random.randn(len(t1)) * 0.04
# x coordinates for the lines
xcoords = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
# colors for the lines
colors = ['r','k','b']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.scatter(t1, f(t1 + noise), color = 'hotpink', label='Values obtained by experiment', edgecolors='k')
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), ls='solid', label='Theoretical expectation', color='b')
plt.title(r'This is latex title example $\mathbf{E = m \times c^2}$', fontsize='small')
plt.xlabel("This is X-label.", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("This is Y-label.", fontsize=16)
for xc,c in zip(xcoords,colors):
    plt.axvline(x=xc, label='line at x = {}'.format(xc), c=c)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc=(1.15,0.2))
```

[image: BoldTick]